# Rust-like error handling in Kotlin using `?`, is it possible?

Tags: kotlin

The code below has several possible failures. For example, `width` could be null, or `r` could be false. In all cases, I should return a `result.error()` or something like that.

```
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    } else if (call.method=="registerTexture") {
      val entry: TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry = texture_registry.createSurfaceTexture();
      val surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture();
      //TODO: return non-sucess when no width and height passed
      val width: Int = call.argument("width")!!
      val height: Int = call.argument("height")!!
      surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height)
      val response = HashMap<String, Long>()
      RendererPlugin.surfaceTextureMap.put(entry, surfaceTexture)
      val r = RendererPlugin.registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler(entry.id(), surfaceTexture)
      if (!r) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "attention: failed result from registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler")
      }
      response.put("textureId", entry.id())
      result.success(response)
    }
  }
```

On Rust, I'd make all of this into a closure which results `Result<(), Error>` and then execute the closure inside `onMethodCall` and if I got an error, I'd return an error. Also, the closure would be full of calls ending with `?` so it automatically returns the error that has a `From<>` implementation that converts to `Error`.

**How can I do this efficiently in Kotlin? Is there a way to make a closure and also easily return success or error in this closure, and then based on this result I call `result.sucess` or `result.error`?**

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps you.

Pay attention: I assume that `result.success()` accepts `Any` because you return `String` or `HashMap` as a parameter, but `kotlin.Result` doesn't have several generic success parameters. You can play with `kotlin.Pair<A, B>` as the success type of `kotlin.Result` :D

```
override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    val finalResult: kotlin.Result<Any> = call.run {
        if (method == "getPlatformVersion") kotlin.Result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
        else if (method == "registerTexture") {
            val entry: TextureRegistry.SurfaceTextureEntry = texture_registry.createSurfaceTexture();
            val surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture();
            val width = argument("width") ?: return@run kotlin.Result.failure(IllegalArgumentException("width is null"))
            val height = argument("height") ?: return@run kotlin.Result.failure(IllegalArgumentException("height is null"))

            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height)
            val response = HashMap<String, Long>()
            RendererPlugin.surfaceTextureMap.put(entry, surfaceTexture)
            val r = RendererPlugin.registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler(entry.id(), surfaceTexture)
            if (!r) return@run kotlin.Result.failure(IllegalArgumentException("r is false"))
            response.put("textureId", entry.id())
            kotlin.Result.success(response)
        }
        else kotlin.Result.failure(IllegalStateException("undefined call.method"))
    }

    with (finalResult) {
        onSuccess(result::success)
        onFailure(result::fail)
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a place where I can read about `return@run`? It makes no sense to me

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, sure — https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html

Comment: is @run really needed in this case?

Comment: Yes. Bare `return` calls are not allowed inside lambdas because it would be ambiguous which function you want to return from.

Comment: I am getting `Unresolved reference: kotin` and also `Unresolved reference: fail`

Comment: @PPP, I fixed `kotin`, thank you :)



The `Result` type is implemented by the author of the question, it is not equal to `kotlin.Result`. You can implement the `result::success` and `result::fail` methods by yourself

Answer (score 5):

There's a `runCatching` function you can call on anything. Within the following lambda closure, the object you called it on is "`this`". You can either return something for success, or throw something for failure. Then you can unpack this result into your `Result` object. `error()`, `require()` and `check()` are useful ways to throw under a certain condition without interrupting the flow of your code.

To return something from a lambda enclosure, you can either manually do it with `return@nameOfFunctionLambdaIsPassedTo`, or let the last expression of the lambda be the return value. A `when` expression can be used as the last (only) expression of your lambda, so the last thing in each branch of the `when` is the successful returned result (or a thrown error).

Here's an example:

```
override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    call.runCatching {
        when(method) {
            "getPlatformVersion" -> "Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}"
            "registerTexture" -> {
                 val entry = texture_registry.createSurfaceTexture()
                 val surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture()
                 val width: Int = argument("width") ?: error("no width passed")
                 val height: Int = argument("height") ?: error("no height passed")
                 surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height)
                 RendererPlugin.surfaceTextureMap.put(entry, surfaceTexture)
                 check(RendererPlugin.registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler(entry.id(), surfaceTexture)) {
                     "attention: failed result from registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler"
                 }
                 mapOf("textureId", entry.id())
            }
            else -> error("unsupported method name: $method")
        }
    }
        .onSuccess(result::success)
        .onFailure(result::failure)
}
```

If you want to avoid having to call `onSuccess`/`onFailure`, you can create a generic extension function you could use repeatedly like this:

```
inline fun MethodCall.runForResult(result: Result, block: MethodCall.() -> Any) {
    runCatching(block).onSuccess(result::success).onFailure(result::failure)
}
```

```
override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    call.runForResult(result) {
        when(method) {
            "getPlatformVersion" -> "Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}"
            "registerTexture" -> {
                 val entry = texture_registry.createSurfaceTexture()
                 val surfaceTexture = entry.surfaceTexture()
                 val width: Int = argument("width") ?: error("no width passed")
                 val height: Int = argument("height") ?: error("no height passed")
                 surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(width, height)
                 RendererPlugin.surfaceTextureMap.put(entry, surfaceTexture)
                 check(RendererPlugin.registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler(entry.id(), surfaceTexture)) {
                     "attention: failed result from registerSurfaceTextureNativeHandler"
                 }
                 mapOf("textureId", entry.id())
            }
            else -> error("unsupported method name: $method")
        }
    }
}
```